# Variable 'module' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, npm-install

I'm working on an [Angular](http://angular.io) project and recently installed [ng2-dropdown-treeview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dropdown-treeview) 1.0.5. After installing, I restarted my server with `npm start`.

My server log is printing the following error:

```
[PATH]\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts:82:13
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'module' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'.
```

I navigated to index.d.ts:82 and changed `declare var module: NodeModule;` to `declare var module: any`, as per the error.

But it led to an error in my devtools console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function.
```

And it's pointing to vendor.bundle.js.35429:

```
// API of tsickle for lowering decorators to properties on the class.
if (__webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__facade_lang__["e" /* isPresent */])(typeOrFunc.ctorParameters)) {
    var ctorParameters = typeOrFunc.ctorParameters;
    var paramTypes_1 = ctorParameters.map(function (ctorParam /** TODO #9100 */) { return ctorParam && ctorParam.type; });
    var paramAnnotations_1 = ctorParameters.map(function (ctorParam /** TODO #9100 */) {
        return ctorParam && convertTsickleDecoratorIntoMetadata(ctorParam.decorators);
    });
    return this._zipTypesAndAnnotations(paramTypes_1, paramAnnotations_1);
```

I'm already averse to changing packaged code like this, so I figured that I'd ask if anyone else has had a similar issue. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you may have a duplicate variable def in one of your `.d.ts`s.  What type defs have you included?  Can you reduce the problem to using a minimum number of modules?

Comment: @SandyGifford, thanks for jumping in. I've got `declare module '*';` in custom-types.d.ts, which is the only place where I thought that there could be a conflict.

But since it's a wildcard, it shouldn't conflict, right? Even so, I changed it to `declare var module: any;` just to be safe, and it's still giving me the same issue :(

Comment: That could cause a problem.  Can you try recreating the problem in a new project with just those two defs and enough code to load them?

Comment: So, it turned out that the problem was related to a conflict with [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd). Once I removed all references to ng2-dnd, and changed `declare var module: any`, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps a problem with its `.d.ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the issue was a dependency conflict with [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd). Once its references were removed from the application, the errors were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen instead of "any" it was "string". Somehow I accidentally added an extra import that was causing issues.

```
import { element } from 'protractor';
```

This was my offender. If anyone else is having this problem, maybe start pulling out some of your imports until you figure out which one you added is causing this to happen.